# Process a list of lists in Prolog (Go game)

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence

I am suffering from this Prolog predicate: `board(Before,_,After)`.

Where `Before` is a list of lists of character, either ‘a’, ‘b’, ‘c’, or ‘d’ (and the length of lists inside the list are same). For example:

```
[[c,c,c,c,c],[a,a,a,a,c],[a,b,b,a,c],[b,d,b,a,c],[d,b,b,a,c]]
```

To obtain After, first represent Before as below:

```
  ccccc
  aaaac
  abbac
  bdbac
  dbbac
```

Actually this is a board state of a Go game (this case is 5x5). The ‘c’s and ‘d’s are vacant spaces. The ‘a’s are white stones and ‘b’s are black stones. Always map each ‘c’ and ‘d’ to ‘rr’. Map ‘a’ to ‘ar’ if it is alive, to ‘ad’ if dead. Similarly for the ‘b’s. In this case,

```
?- board([[c,c,c,c,c],[a,a,a,a,c],[a,b,b,a,c],[b,d,b,a,c],[d,b,b,a,c]],_,After).
After = [[rr,rr,rr,rr,rr],[ar,ar,ar,ar,rr],[ar,br,br,ar,rr],[br,rr,br,ar,rr],[rr,br,br,ar,rr]]
```

Actually I have tried to use DFS to solve this problem but I failed. Can those who know Prolog and some basic rules of Go implement this predicate? Thanks a lot!

Comment: what is "dead" and what is "alive" in Go? ... you're supposed to ask for help with *coding* here, not with game rules comprehension.

Comment: In Go, a shape is considered alive if it has two eyes (two holes that the other color cannot play within) and dead if it cannot create two eyes. Shapes are often undecided. I don't know if one would really talk about a stone as being alive or dead though. (I'm very inexperienced at Go).